# Jquery Blue-imp file-upload submitting additional data to a db when uploading multiple files

Tags: jquery, database, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using Blue-imp file-upload to upload files.  I've created a cusomUploadHandler as follows to allow additional data to be persisted to the database as follows: (I got the code from some tutorial online - but can't find it now)

```
class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function initialize() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->options['db_host'],
            $this->options['db_user'],
            $this->options['db_pass'],
            $this->options['db_name']
        );
        parent::initialize();
        $this->db->close();
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
        $file->description = @$_REQUEST['payroll_type'];
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }

    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->type = $type;
                $file->title = $title;
                $file->description = $description;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($print_response = true) {
        $response = parent::delete(false);
        foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
            if ($deleted) {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'
                    .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
                $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $query->bind_param('s', $name);
                $query->execute();
            }
        } 
        return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
    }

}
```

My problem is that when there are multiple files uploaded the CustomUploadHandler is called several times and it doesn't submit the data in the description to the database. Only the last record is persisted correctly.  Here's the HTML for the form:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/assets/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/UploadHandler.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
                                    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                                            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                                            <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                <span>
                                                     Add files...
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="">
                                            </span>
                                            <!-- The global file processing state -->
                                            <span class="fileupload-process">
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- The global progress information -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                                            <!-- The global progress bar -->
                                            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                                            <div class="progress-extended">
                                                 &nbsp;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                                    <div class="well">
                                        <table role="presentation" class="table clearfix" >
                                            <tbody class="files">
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Each of file titles are being correctly persisted, but it is a problem with the dropdown select options that is lost when there are multiple file uploads.  The select boxes look like this:

```
 <select id="payroll_type" class="form-control" name="payroll_type">
   <option name="payroll_variations" value="">Select File Type</option>
       <option name="payroll_variations" value="Payroll Variations">Payroll Variations</option>
       <option name="starters" value="Starters">Starters</option>
       <option name="leavers" value="Leavers">Leavers</option>
       <option name="ss_changes" value="Master Data Changes">Master Data Changes</option>
 </select>
```

And the only file that has it's description saved is the last one in the queue.  All the previous files will have lost the value selected in their respective select option.

Sorry I don't know how to explain this better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this answer is so late.
In my case there was no reason in supplying data if the file didn't upload; so I made uploading then gathering data about the files a two step process.

I added the additional inputs required to the template that displays the uploaded files. (blue imp has this labeled as "download template)

A single save button kicks off javascript function to update file data.
Within that function JQRY visits each row of the "download template" it creates a JSON object to transfer the data to be saved.  Then posts to a "web method" in the aspx code behind.

Details:

slight modification to blue Imp download template

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr style="width:96%" class="template-download{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    {{if error}}

        <td class="name" style="width:30%" colspan=2>${namefdsa}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2">Error:
            {{if error === 1}}File exceeds upload_max_filesize (php.ini directive)
            {{else error === 2}}File exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE (HTML form directive)
            {{else error === 3}}File was only partially uploaded
            {{else error === 4}}No File was uploaded
            {{else error === 5}}Missing a temporary folder
            {{else error === 6}}Failed to write file to disk
            {{else error === 7}}File upload stopped by extension
            {{else error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big
            {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small
            {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype not allowed
            {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
            {{else error === 'uploadedBytes'}}Uploaded bytes exceed file size
            {{else error === 'emptyResult'}}Empty file upload result
            {{else}}${error}
            {{/if}}
        </td>
        <td></td>
    {{else}}
        <td class="name" style="width:15%">
           <a href="${Thumbnail_url}" target="_blank">${reNamed}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size" style="width:5%">${Length}</td>
        <td style="width:40%"><textarea  style='HEIGHT: 60px;width:90%' rows='2' >(Describe File)</textarea> </td>
        <td class='hdn'> ${DocID}</td>
    {{/if}}
    <td class="delete">
        <button data-type="${delete_type}" data-url="${delete_url}">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

core of the javascript function to save all description text areas per file

```
$("table.files tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'template-download') {
            var DocID = $(this).children("td:eq(3)").text();
            var descptn = $(this).children("td:eq(2)").children('textarea').val();
            var objDD = new Object();
            objDD.ID = DocID;
            objDD.sDescription = descptn;
            objDD.sTyp = 'efs';

            // Create a data transfer object (DTO) with the proper structure.
            var DTO = { 'dd': objDD };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Upload.aspx/saveDesc',
                data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.d.status != "success") {
                        msgAlert_js('unable to update document.' + response.d.msg);
                    }

                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    msgAlert_js('unavoidable unknown error');
                },
                processData: false
            });
        }
    });
```

code behind web method to accept the data one file at a time

```
[WebMethod] //async web method to update the decription of each file uploaded
    public static basicResult saveDesc(docDescription dd)//string sTyp, int ID,string docDescription
    {
        basicResult rslt = new basicResult();


        try
        {
                // here work with  dd.ID,  dd.sDescription
                //let save function return good result
                //  rslt.status = "success";
                //  rslt.msg = string.Empty;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string stop;
            rslt.status = "error";
            rslt.msg = e.Message;
        }
        return rslt;
    }
```

where result isnt more than this class

```
public class basicResult
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```